# PHP CLI Timeout Issue

Tags: linux, timeout, php

I have a PHP CLI script that continually times out, and I can't figure out the source of the timeout. Seemingly "randomly" the script will stop (with no PHP error in the logs) and give the following output to console:

```
timeout, elapsed_time = 60
```

I'm setting PHP's time limit via `set_time_limit(0);` intermittently but it doesn't seem to be making a difference.

Besides that, PHP is supposed to throw an error if it hits its timeout, and no error is thrown, so could this timeout be triggered by something other than PHP?

The script is started by a bash script ".sh" on a Ubuntu machine.

Thanks!

Comment: PHP CLI should have no timeout by default, meaning you shouldn't have to explicitly call `set_time_limit(0);` - My hunch would be that it's something other than PHP itself (PHP does not generate an error that looks like the one you have posted, when the execution time limit is hit) - It's still possible that a component of your script is generating this output though.

Comment: Take a look into the script first, *what* is generating that output? Also how are you invoking the script? Maybe it's a systems hard limit? What is the return code of the script?

Comment: Maybe something is killing the bash script and its children?

Comment: The bash script sets DISPLAY and kills a couple processes that could interfere with the script, then starts the script with "/usr/bin/php <path and script name>.php". It then waits for the PHP script to finish, and performs a bit of cleanup. Could the issue be in the bash script? I agree that it doesn't really seem like a PHP timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who helped me out.

I tried running the script through `nohup` and the timeout issue seems to have disappeared. Hope this helps someone else!